# Spring @Value not getting set

Tags: spring, properties

I'm sure this has been asked 1000 times, because i've seen them, however I'm missing something.

Context:

```
<beans profile="localDev">
    <util:properties id="propertiesLocalDev"location="classpath:/localDev.properties"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="test">
    <util:properties id="properties-test" location="classpath:/test.properties"/>
</beans>
```

Init:

```
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "localDev");
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
    ctx.refresh();
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {


@Value("${test.value}")
private String testValue;
...
```

Logs:

```
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [localDev.properties]
```

Properties:

```
test.value=ugh
```

So it seems the properties are getting read, however the the value in AppConfig.testValue is not getting set.   I have tried pure java java/xml etc...  Some configs break some work, tried using @PropertySource, but the constant is testValue never gets set, so I'm fundamentally doing something wrong.

The overall goal is to load different properties files depending on different profiles.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will also a need a [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) which can resolve the property for you. This is configured using:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="..." 
                local-override="true" properties-ref="propertiesLocalDev" />
```

With this your property value should resolve cleanly.

This also should work - using Spring-EL:

```
@Value("#{@propertiesLocalDev['test.value']}")
private String testValue;
```

Comment: My understanding is that <util:properties id="propertiesLocalDev" location="classpath:/localDev.properties"/> supersedes property-placeholder.

Comment: util:properties just creates a properties bean. To resolve the property references within other beans you will still need a propertyplaceholder.

Comment: just tried it, it just reads the properties file twice now, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class AppConfig {

 @Autowired
private String testValue;

}
```

If the variable is properly autowired you can use

```
String sUgh = testValue.getProperty("test.value"); // = "ugh"
```

I alsou would use plain

```
<util:properties id="propertiesLocalDev"location="classpath:/localDev.properties"/>
```

instead of using the

```
<beans profile>
```

tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like, in XML only use following

```
<util:properties id="test" location="classpath:fn-test-configuration.properties" />
```

Now, following way you can use the property values in class

@Value("#{test.test.value}") 
private String testValue;

I have used the same way and it is working fine.

Comment: i have it in the profile, because i want to load different properties files per environment.

Comment: I did this:  **<util:properties id="localDev" location="classpath:localDev.properties" />**
Then this: **@Value("#{localDev['test.value']}")
    private String testValue;**
And nothing happens, but i can see in the logs its reading the properties file.  Its just not setting the value.
This breaks it though: **@Value("#{localDev.test.value}")**